# Alien not defined

Tags: python-3.x

For some reason, the python window says Alien not defined.

alien.py:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
class Alien(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        super(Alien, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.image = pygame.image.load('alien.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
    def check_edges(self):
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rect.right >= screen_rect.right:
            return True
        elif self.rect.left <= 0:
            return True

    def update(self):
        self.x += (self.ai_settings.alien_speed_factor *
                        self.ai_settings.fleet_direction)
        self.rect.x = self.x

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

alien_invasion.py:

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf
import random
from pygame.sprite import Group
from alien import Alien
class Square(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, size1, size2, colour):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([size1, size2])
        self.image.fill(colour)


        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x=x
        self.rect.y=y

allspriteslist = pygame.sprite.Group()

for i in range(1, 250):
    num = random.randint(1,3)
    stars = Square(random.randint(0, 1000), random.randint(0, 700), num, num, (255, 255, 255))
    allspriteslist.add(stars)

def run_game():
    pygame.init()

    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("PEWPEWPEWPOWPOW DIE YOU LITTLE ALIEN ____S ")
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
    bullets = Group()
    aliens = Group()
    gf.create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)

    while True:
        gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        ship.update()
        gf.update_bullets(bullets)
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, alien, bullets)
        allspriteslist.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()


run_game()
```

bullet.py:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Bullet(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, ship):
        super(Bullet, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, ai_settings.bullet_width,
            ai_settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
        self.rect.top = ship.rect.top
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)
        self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
        self.speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor
    def update(self):
        self.y -= self.speed_factor
        self.rect.y = self.y
    def draw_bullet(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

game_functions.py:

```
import sys
import pygame
from bullet import Bullet

def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
    elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
        sys.exit

def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False

def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ship)

def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_colour)
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    ship.blitme()
    aliens.draw(screen)

def update_bullets(bullets):
    bullets.update()
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
            bullets.remove(bullet)

def fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    if len(bullets) < ai_settings.bullets_allowed:
        new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
        bullets.add(new_bullet)

def get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship_height, alien_height):
    available_space_y = (ai_settings.screen_height -
                            (3 * alien_height) - ship_height)
    number_rows = int(available_space_y / (2 * alien_height))
    return number_rows

def create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number, row_number):
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    alien_width = alien.rect.width
    alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
    alien.rect.x = alien.x
    alien.rect.y = alien.rect.height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number
    aliens.add(alien)

def create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens):
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    number_aliens_x = get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien.rect.width)
    number_rows = get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship.rect.height,
        alien.rect.height)
```

settings.py:

```
class Settings():
    def __init__(self):
        #screen stuff
        self.screen_width = 1000
        self.screen_height = 750
        self.bg_colour = (0, 0, 0)
        self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5
        self.bullet_speed_factor = 1
        self.bullet_width = 3
        self.bullet_height = 15
        self.bullet_color = 0, 255, 0
        self.bullets_allowed = 7
```

ship.py:

```
import pygame

class Ship():
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.image = pygame.image.load('ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)
    def update(self):
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        self.rect.centerx = self.center
    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

I'm getting an error message that `Alien` is not defined when I run this code, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

How is the `game_functions.py` file meant to know about the `Alien` it uses in `createAlien()` and `createFleet()`?

Python is good, but it can't read minds :-) I think you probably need to import the alien stuff into that file.